# Getting full string stack trace including inner exception

Tags: java, stack-trace

Java's e.printStackTrace() doesn't print all the details of the inner exception's stack trace.

Is there a ready way to generate the complete stack trace in string form? (besides formatting it myself)

**Edit**

I just found out what printStackTrace() does - apparently the stack frames it filters out are exactly the ones common to the inner exception and the outer one. So in fact it is rather what I want, and not the 'full' stack trace.

Comment: How do you mean - inner exception's stack trace? Is a caught exception being propagated in another exception?

Comment: Something that's produces by a catch ... throw new Exception("foo", e)

Comment: I just found out what printStackTrace() does - apparently the stack frames it filters out are exactly the ones common to the inner exception and the outer one. So in fact it is rather what I want, and not the 'full' stack trace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own (I took the implementation of Throwable.printStackTrace() and tweaked it a bit):

```
public static String joinStackTrace(Throwable e) {
    StringWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new StringWriter();
        joinStackTrace(e, writer);
        return writer.toString();
    }
    finally {
        if (writer != null)
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // ignore
            }
    }
}

public static void joinStackTrace(Throwable e, StringWriter writer) {
    PrintWriter printer = null;
    try {
        printer = new PrintWriter(writer);

        while (e != null) {

            printer.println(e);
            StackTraceElement[] trace = e.getStackTrace();
            for (int i = 0; i < trace.length; i++)
                printer.println("\tat " + trace[i]);

            e = e.getCause();
            if (e != null)
                printer.println("Caused by:\r\n");
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (printer != null)
            printer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you missed to print stack trace for inner exception here? `if (e != null)                 printer.println("Caused by:\r\n");`

Comment: something like `printer.println("Caused by:\r\n"+joinStackTrace(e))`?

Answer (score 9):

I suggest that you use the [ExceptionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html) class from Apache Commons lang, which provides useful method for that.

Comment: Actually, getFullStacktrace() still doesn't print the inner stack trace.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no printFullStacktrace() method, but you can do System.err.println(getFullStacktrace());

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the  StackTraceElement class returned by Throwable.getStackTrace() and find the details.

From the API:

> The last element of the array  (assuming the array's length is
>   non-zero) represents the bottom of the  stack, which is the first method
>   invocation in the sequence.