# How can i take a thread dump exactly when many outofmemory error occur?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-dump

I had run a jvm process, one day it encountered the outofmemory exception. In the log I have found many outofmemory errors::

> ```
> -bash-3.00# grep OutOfMemoryError AdminServer.log00399
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> ####<2013-6-28 05:09:27 pm CST> <Error> <Server> <kfmsapp2> <AdminServer> <DynamicListenThread[Default[3]]> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <>
> ```
>
> <1372410567863>

It also generated a heapdump file, I found it was a big object from a thread after analysing by using mat, I just know it's a hibernate common object `org.hibernate.engine.PersistenceContext`, but I don't know where it come from.

I want to write a small program, and it will generate a threaddump file automatically when the outofmemory error occured.

My question is: what time of the program executing is best to take a thread dump exactly? Is it on the first outofmemory error appear in the log file?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably try to use an [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> allStackTraces = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
            // print it ...
        }
    });

            // ... continuing
}
```

For printing, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/stacktrace-to-string-in-java) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292858/getting-full-string-stack-trace-including-inner-exception).